# Cannot retrieve Firebase data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter project and am using Firebase. All is working fine, I can read, write update the data. However, in one of my classes, I need to get a List of one of my attributes from Firebase:

```
var accountNames = List<String>();

  _getData(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> accountList = [];

    final accounts = _database.collection('userAccounts').getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
          accountNames.add(f['accountName']);
          print(accountNames); //first call
      });
    }); // non_updated_area 
    print(accountNames); //second call
}
```

Here, my first call to `accountName`  gives the correct output. However the second call gives `null` . I tried several options like returning a function of List, Widget etc but couldn't reach the updated `accountNames`  outside of the `non_updated_area` .

Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Does the second call run before the first one ie. do you see null, then the correct list?

Comment: That's true @GrahamD, the output is like: ```flutter: []
Reloaded 13 of 568 libraries in 369ms.
flutter: [list_item]```

Comment: The Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two completely separate database. Please in the future only tag with the database that you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your second print statement runs before the call to the database has finished so there has been no data returned for it to print. Not sure why you need the second print of the same information but if you intend to replace that print with some processing of the data then it would not work there. You need to process the data returned within the `.then` block. Alternatively you need to make use of the async / await construct in Dart.

**UPDATE**
Given you comment:

> Well, my goal here is to reach updated accountNames list outside of this function. Eg. calling this from another function or Widget. How can I pass data outside of the .then block?

There are several ways but the simplest, given your code, would be to change this function to a Future> and use a return statement in the `.then` block, something like:

```
Future<List<String>> getData(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> accountNames = List<String>();

  _database.collection('userAccounts').getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
          accountNames.add(f['accountName']);
      });
      return accountNames;
    });
}
```

Then call it like:

```
var accountNameList = await getData(context);
```

Comment: Well, my goal here is to reach updated ```accountNames ``` list outside of this function. Eg. calling this from another function or Widget. How can I pass data outside of the ```.then ``` block?

Answer (score 1):

Since `getDocuments()` is asynchronous then the data outside the `then()` method will be called before fully retrieving the data from firestore.

You can use `async` and `await`:

```
 _getData(BuildContext context) async {
    List<String> accountList = [];

    final accounts = await _database.collection('userAccounts').getDocuments();
      accounts.documents.forEach((f) {
          accountNames.add(f['accountName']);
          print(accountNames);
      }); 
    print(accountNames); //second call
}
```